# Google Apps Script: The script completed but did not return anything

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Once again I'm reaching out to you for help.

I'm trying to import data from Apple Health to Google Sheets. Script worked yesterday but for some reason it stopped working when I added the replace variables. I tried to undo changes and re-deployed the script but it didn't help.
I have Shortcut set up in my iPhone which runs each day at 3pm and in Google Sheets I have following code:

```
function doGet(e) {

  var healthSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1RoviwpSK25qAjy02AILSuVTHbba4X4wULc0cNBKybQs").getSheetByName("Health");
  var weight = JSON.parse(e.parameters.weight);
  var bfp = JSON.parse(e.parameters.bfp);
  var bmi = JSON.parse(e.parameters.bmi);
  var lbm = JSON.parse(e.parameters.lbm);

  var weightCom = String(weight).replace('.', ',');
  var bfpCom = String(bfp).replace('.', ',');
  var bmiCom = String(bmi).replace('.', ',');
  var lbmCom = String(lbm).replace('.', ',');

  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-3", "dd.MM.yyyy");


 healthSheet.appendRow([formattedDate,weightCom,bmiCom,bfpCom,lbmCom]);
  
}
```

Replace variables are used bc Apple Health sends values with decimal point and I live in Finland where decimal comma is used.

Deploy settings are following:

Deployment type: Web App
Execute as: Me
Who has access: Anyone

I have checked that Apple Health has data registered with date 7.6.2022 so that shouldn't be the problem.

Thank you in advance for all the help

Comment: What do you mean by it "stopped working"? Did the script not fire/start? Was no data returned? An error has occurred?

Comment: Try using the debugger to figure what's going wrong.

Comment: As mentioned in the previous comments, please be more specific in what exactly stopped working. Seems like you're sending data to the Apps Script deployment from the Apple shortcut. You can check the "Executions" section in GAS to see if the script is even being run at all, do tests with sample data, etc. More information is needed to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

As Cooper said, use debugger. I would add some Logger.log() to see what exactly you are appending:

```
function doGet(e) {

  var healthSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1RoviwpSK25qAjy02AILSuVTHbba4X4wULc0cNBKybQs").getSheetByName("Health");
  var weight = JSON.parse(e.parameters.weight);
  var bfp = JSON.parse(e.parameters.bfp);
  var bmi = JSON.parse(e.parameters.bmi);
  var lbm = JSON.parse(e.parameters.lbm);

  var weightCom = String(weight).replace('.', ',');
  var bfpCom = String(bfp).replace('.', ',');
  var bmiCom = String(bmi).replace('.', ',');
  var lbmCom = String(lbm).replace('.', ',');

  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-3", "dd.MM.yyyy");

   Logger.log("formattedDate=",formattedDate);
   Logger.log("weightCom",weightCom);
   Logger.log("bmiCom",bmiCom);
   Logger.log("bfpCom",bfpCom);
   Logger.log("lbmCom",lbmCom);


 healthSheet.appendRow([formattedDate,weightCom,bmiCom,bfpCom,lbmCom]);
  
}
```